# Why am I getting 401 UnauthorizedError when getting a list of events using the SocialTables API?

Tags: social-tables

I am trying to use the API Console to get access to event information. When I use `https://api.socialtables.com/4.0/events/` I get a 401 response code, where I expect to see a list of events that I have created.

I am the owner on the account, and other calls in the API Console are working. I can query `https://api.socialtables.com/4.0/users/` with my user id and `https://api.socialtables.com/4.0/accounts/` with my account id.

I get the same behavior when calling the API from Postman.

*Update*

I was able to find my team id by inspecting the URL. It appeared to be an legacy numeric id, so I tried one of the legacy endpoints:

`https://api.socialtables.com/4.0/legacyvm3/teams/[TEAM-ID]/events`

That works, and returns the list of events that I expected. However, it only returns the legacy id values. I'd prefer to strictly use the newer ids and API endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for using our API.  I couldn't reproduce the 401 unauthorized issue, but I noticed our trial signup put you in the 3.0 version, which is why you see your 3.0 events. Our trial process is currently being revised to put people in our latest version, and will do that soon.

In the meantime I went ahead and migrated your account to 4.0 and created a test v4 event.

Using this curl gives me the expected result:

```
curl --request GET \
>   --url https://api.socialtables.com/4.0/events \
>   --header 'authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXade8'
```

If you have further questions I'd be happy to assist.

Comment: I posted a follow-up question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186909/why-does-4-0-events-return-notfounderror-in-the-socialtables-api