# Why does /4.0/events/ return NotFoundError in the SocialTables API?

Tags: social-tables

I create several new events in my account. But when I call this endpoint - `https://api.socialtables.com/4.0/events/` - I always receive a `404` response with this body:

```
{
  "code": "NotFoundError",
  "message": ""
}
```

If I call the legacy endpoint - `https://api.socialtables.com/4.0/legacyvm3/teams/[TEAM-ID]/events` - it returns both the legacy events and the new events. But it only tells me the legacy ID values. I guess that's okay, but it's confusing. It looks like I am unable to use the v4 API at all.

Follow-up from this question: [Why am I getting 401 UnauthorizedError when getting a list of events using the SocialTables API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43142221/why-am-i-getting-401-unauthorizederror-when-getting-a-list-of-events-using-the-s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see it now.  Don't use a trailing slash when requesting the /events route:

`https://api.socialtables.com/4.0/events`

Comment: Thanks Dan! FYI your API Console includes the trailing slash.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm not exactly sure where the disconnect is.  I just ran that endpoint with your most recent oauth token and got the following result:

```
[
  {
    "permissions": [
      "CHANGE_OWNER",
      "ADD_PLANNER",
      "REMOVE_PLANNER",
      "ADD_VIEWER",
      "REMOVE_VIEWER",
      "ADD_CHECKIN",
      "REMOVE_CHECKIN",
      "UPDATE_EVENT",
      "DELETE_EVENT",
      "UPDATE_GUEST",
      "DELETE_GUEST",
      "CREATE_GUEST",
      "CHECKIN_GUEST",
      "CAN_VIEW"
    ],
    "data": {
      "id": "19fdb5e0-1874-11e7-a3a0-65cadad84d84",
      "name": "Test Event 5",
      "type": "Athletic Event",
      "description": null,
      "start_epoch": 1492660800000,
      "end_epoch": 1492660800000,
      "archived": 0,
      "deleted": 0,
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "has_time": 1,
      "timezone": null,
      "legacy_id": 1962925,
      "industry": "Corporate",
      "role": "owner"
    }
  },
  {
    "permissions": [
      "CHANGE_OWNER",
      "ADD_PLANNER",
      "REMOVE_PLANNER",
      "ADD_VIEWER",
      "REMOVE_VIEWER",
      "ADD_CHECKIN",
      "REMOVE_CHECKIN",
      "UPDATE_EVENT",
      "DELETE_EVENT",
      "UPDATE_GUEST",
      "DELETE_GUEST",
      "CREATE_GUEST",
      "CHECKIN_GUEST",
      "CAN_VIEW"
    ],
    "data": {
      "id": "e77c8e50-1703-11e7-a3a0-65cadad84d84",
      "name": "test event v4",
      "type": "Ceremony",
      "description": null,
      "start_epoch": null,
      "end_epoch": null,
      "archived": 0,
      "deleted": 0,
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "has_time": 0,
      "timezone": null,
      "legacy_id": 1962858,
      "industry": "Education",
      "role": "owner"
    }
  }
]
```

Here's a curl of what I did minus your real token.

```
curl --request GET \
  --url https://api.socialtables.com/4.0/events \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX7063f'
```

How are you retrieving your token?